# Laplacian with Robin Boundary Conditions

Tags: calculus, geometry, partial-differential-equations

Question:

$\bigtriangledown^2u=0, r<a$

$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}+\gamma u = h(\theta), r=a$

This one is giving me a hard time.

I guess $u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$

and get somewhere for the pde... but the Bonundary Conditions .. I have no idea what to do with.

Question states to solve and write the answer in terms of Fourier coefficients of $h$.

please help

Comment: Robin Boundary Conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step solution with details to be filled in:

- Apply separation of variables $u=R\Theta$ to the [Laplacian in polar-coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions): $\nabla^2u = u_{rr} + \frac{u_r}{r} + \frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^2} = 0$ to get the two equations

$$R_{rr} + \frac{R_r}{r} - \frac{k^2R}{r^2} = 0$$
$$\Theta_{\theta\theta} + k^2\Theta = 0$$

- Solve for $\Theta$ and based on the solution give an argument for why $k$ has to be integer (and why we only need only consider $k\geq 0$).
- For $R(r)$ try a test solution $R = r^n$ to find the two solutions. Discard the solution that is not finite at $r=0$.
- The steps above gives us that the most general solution can be written $u(r,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k\left(A_k\sin(k \theta) + B_k\cos(k\theta)\right)$
- Apply the boundary condition to the expression above to get $h(\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(ka^{k-1}  +\gamma a^k\right)\left(A_k\sin(k \theta) + B_k\cos(k\theta)\right)$.
- Finally expand $h$ in a Fourier series $h(\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k \sin(k\theta) + \beta_k \sin(k\theta)$ and compare with the formula above to get an expression for $A_k,B_k$ in terms of the Fourier coeficients ($\alpha_k,\beta_k$) of $h$. This will give you

$$u(r,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(r/a)^k}{k/a + \gamma}\left(\alpha_k\sin(k \theta) + \beta_k\cos(k\theta)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks :) I think I can role with this for sure.

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: @renegade05 I guess someone, without feeling the need to say why, didn't think this was a useful answer. I have double-checked, and this is a pretty straight forward problem, so I really doubt the answer is wrong.